# Network Traffic Pricing between different locations - Azure -

Tags: azure

I need to know if network traffic between different location has cost.

I will deploy a checkpoint firewall cluster. One node on East US and the other one on Central US.

The traffic between them has cost? How can I calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case you'll be charged for the network-out. You should inspect the pricing (Azure Calculator) for a better estimation of your future cost:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/